# How to analyze a Maven pom.xml for mistakes (a pom linter for redundant or ignored properties?)

Tags: java, maven, static-analysis

My `pom.xml` is messy, having collected cruft over time.  Is there any automated way to "clean up" a pom?  Like a linter but for maven.

In IntelliJ I can run `Analyze > Inspect Code` and get a list of unused functions, silly iterators, and probable bugs.  I think I'm looking for the same thing for my pom

1. Unused repositories, pluginRepositories
2. Unused properties
3. properties that collide with settings specified within the plugin
4. Dependencies with more recent versions (`mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` works, but doesn't restrict to non-breaking version updates)

Comment: 1. Repositories are usually not defined in the POM, but in the `settings.xml`. 2. To determine whether a property is used or not would mean to look inside the plugin code. 3. Maybe this could be done 4. How do you know if a version is non-breaking? If you want to avoid major upgrades, there a parameter for that.

Comment: Maven itself warns you about certain mistakes. When you let your project build do you see some? An upgrade to maven 3.5 or so also helped because you get colored output... Eclipse gives you basic info when your pom has some redundant stuff inside. But I don't know anything to the extend what you describe/want...

Answer (score 0):

For a simple static analysis of your `pom.xml`, you can use the [lint-maven-plugin](https://github.com/lewisd32/lint-maven-plugin).

1. Add the following to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.lewisd</groupId>
      <artifactId>lint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.11</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

2. Run the `lint:check` goal to check your `pom.xml` for violations.

```sh
$ mvn lint:check
```

The plugin will report any violations in your `pom.xml` as demonstrated below.

```
[INFO] --- lint-maven-plugin:0.0.11:check (default-cli) @ maven-sample ---
[INFO] Writing summary report
[INFO] [LINT] Completed with 3 violations
[INFO] [LINT] OSSDevelopersSectionRule: missing <developers/> section : 0:0 : /Users/jdoe/workspace/maven-sample/pom.xml
[INFO] [LINT] OSSInceptionYearRule: missing <inceptionYear/> information : 0:0 : /Users/jdoe/workspace/maven-sample/pom.xml
[INFO] [LINT] GAVOrder: Found 'name' but was expecting 'packaging' : 19:8 : /Users/jdoe/workspace/maven-sample/pom.xml
```

You can see a list of available rules by running the `lint:list` goal.

Comment: In a way this is a good answer, but that linter got its last commit in 2015 and the About text on GitHub says "No longer supported": https://github.com/lewisd32/lint-maven-plugin

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like there isn't a pom.xml linter like jshint.com that I can paste my pom into and get advice out.